Can we say that $1^\infty$ is indeterminate because we can't classify $\infty$ as even or odd?
While studying indeterminate forms I like many others had used this post to understand why $1^\infty$ is indeterminate. Today I thought of a new and perhaps simpler argument to explain why this is so but I couldn't find it among the answers in the post.
My argument is that we can write $1^x = (-1)^{2.x}$
Now if $x = \infty$, then $1^\infty = (-1)^{\infty}$,
Which is only true if we can say infinity is even or odd which we can't say.
So, am I correct, or I have made some mistakes in my assumptions.

In the case of $1^{\infty}$ , the parity plays no role. We have $1^x=1$ for every real $x$. But $1^{\infty}$ is in fact indeterminate since for example $(1+x)^{1/x}$ tends to $e$ for $x\to 0$. $(-1)^x$ is not even defined for non-integer values. If we only take integer values , THEN your argument applies that $\infty$ is no number , neither even nor odd.

Also, the exponential laws only hold for positive real bases.

@Peter $-1^x = e^{i\pi x}$ is defined for non-integer values.

Without context , everyone would assume that we are in the real numbers. Also, exponential laws do not hold in general for non-real bases.

In general, $1^x \ne (-1)^{2x}$.

Although your argument doesn't bear up, I think you definitely deserve points for creativity, applied speculation, and curiosity.  All valuable and admirable attributes for a mathematician.

Thank you for the kind words

@jjagmath can you please tell why that is so in general?

@Madly_Maths In short, $((-1)^2)^x$ may not equal $(-1)^{2x}$. The usual rule of $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ fails pretty quickly after we go outside elementary context of $a>0$ or integer $c$.

@Madly_Maths Take $x=1/2$. Then $1^x=1^{1/2}=1$ while $(-1)^{2x}=(-1)^1 = -1$.

Thank you for the explanations. I understand.

No, your argument is not correct. The issue of $1^\infty$ being an indeterminate form has nothing to do with integer exponents per se; one is instead interested in real valued exponents approaching $\infty$. It also has nothing to do with changing the base to $-1$, which on the infinitesmal scale of limits is far, far away from $1$; one is instead interested in real valued bases approaching $1$.
I suggest simply reading the accepted answer of the post you linked to. In brief summary, what matters are the values of the expression $b^x$ as one lets the base $b$ approach $1$ and the exponent $x$ approach $\infty$: the limiting value is not well defined. That's what makes the expression $1^\infty$ an indeterminate form.
